# Swap semicolon/colon to P unexpected cause semicolon/colon affected by Cpas Lock

Tags: debian, x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I use `xmodmap -e "keycode  47 = p P p P" -e "keycode  33 = semicolon colon semicolon colon"` to swap <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>semicolon/colon</kbd>
My expected behavior:
`semicolon/colon` don't affected by <kbd>Cpas Lock</kbd> as default behavior in Debian Stretch.
My keyboard information:

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
$ setxkbmap -query -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
$
```